# Thymeleaf th:text attribute value not displaying on index.html for Java 21

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, java-21

I am using the Thymeleaf templating engine to display some info from a Java 21 backend. For some inexplicable reason, the th:text attribute value does not display on the html page. The non-thymeleaf plain HTML display correctly.

My controller file (TemplateController.java):

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TemplateController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String template (Model model) {
        String msg = "Hello World";

        //adding the attribute(key-value pair)
        model.addAttribute("message", msg);

        //returning the view name
        return "index";
    }
}
```

=============================================================

My index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org", lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Image and Text</title>
    <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", charset=UTF-8 />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" />
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Welcome to Geeks Geeks...</h1>
    <div id="one">
       <h1 th:text="${message}"></h1>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

EDITED on 21 Jan 2024: I made corrections. The HTML and CSS are displaying. But the Thymeleaf th:text value still does not appear..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style.css" />
    <title>Image and Text</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Welcome to Geeks Geeks...</h1>
        <p th:text="${message}"></p>
    
</body>

</html>
```

===========================================================
My pol.xml included spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf dependency:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
```

==========================================================
The controller file (TemplateController.java) is at
src/main/java/com/example/demo/

The index.html is under src/main/resources/templates/

I have the "Live Server" extension in VS Code. When I open with the Live Server, I only see my HTML codes. I do not see the anything templated by Thymeleaf.

I tried changing the attributeName in both the TemplateController.java and index.html

```
  model.addAttribute("msg1", msg);
```

but it makes no difference.

I tried directly writing in the message String, but it makes no difference either.

```
 model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World");
```

There are no errors captured by linting, security code scan or Duet AI. Maven build was successful.

It seems very basic but I can't figure out what's wrong. Can anyone spot why Thymeleaf is not displaying the value of the attribute?